# Referencing a Text in Unity Error

Tags: unity, c#

I am working on trying to add a coin system to my game. I have it setup right now so that when the player hits a coin the score text goes up by 1. I have setup a reference in the script, which is attached to the coin, to the score text in my scene. In the game the player can click a button that will switch between two lanes to avoid enemies. These lanes are infinte and in these lanes is where I put the coins. And when a new lane is created the reference to the text disappears from the coin and teh tect does not change. I am not sure why the reference is disappearing.

Here is the coin script that is on the coin

```
public int scoreToGive = 1;

public Text coinText;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        AddScore();
    }
}

public void AddScore()
{
    TheScore.theScore++;
    if(coinText != null)
    {
        coinText.text = TheScore.theScore.ToString();
    }

    Destroy(gameObject);
}

void Update()
{
    coinText.text = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Ui").ToString();
}
```

}

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Those coins and/or lanes are created at runtime? Maybe the probles is that they are instantiated at runtime, so they can't have a scene object reference. What you could do is to have a reference holder, and each time you instantiate a lane and / or coin, you pass the holder's text to each one.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From what I get from your problem, is that each coin has a reference to the Text, your code does not say it, but I want to guess that you instantiate them in run time.

So the problem would be this: when you reference an Object (be it a **GameObject**, **Transform**, or any other component), if it is an object instance belonging to a scene, the reference will be loss one either of them move from that scene, in the case of prefabs the same happens, you may apply changes with a scene object's reference but it won't be saved on the prefab located in the project's folder.

So, what you can do, is to instead have a controller GameObject that holds instantiable objects' references, so when you instance a Coin, that controller passes the needed Text, example (all scripts should be on different files):

```
public class ReferenceInjector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text coinText;
}

public class Coin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;
}

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ReferenceInjector injector;
    public Coin coinPrefab;

    public void CreateCoin(Vector3 position)
    {
        Coin newCoin = Instantiate(coinPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity) as Coin;
        newCoin.text = injector.coinText;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to updating the UI, I personally like using the singleton pattern.

```
public class MyUserInterface : Monobehaviour
{
    public static MyUserInterface instance;

    public Text score;

    void Awake()
    {
         if (instance == null)
              instance = this;
         else if (instance != this)
              Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

If you add this component to any gameObject and set the reference to the Text on the inspector, you can access the Text from anywhere in your code by using the following line:

```
MyUserInterface.instance.score.text = "Your text here";
```